# IoT Hub key regen, old key still works

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub, access-keys, azure-iot-sdk

I have a working IoT Hub, with incoming telemetry. I haven't touched it in months and wanted to go back and check the Permissions on the Shared Access Key that my device is connecting with.
I could not find a Policy with a key matching the one my device is using. I do remember regen'ing keys long ago, and feel like the device key may have been an instance prior to a regen.

Should old keys work after regen'ing?
If so, how else can this SharedAccess key be working, is there a history or other keys I'm not remembering?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It was the primary key of the Device itself, found in the Device Explorer.
However, I'm not sure what permission is given to this key, unless there is an implicit permission given to all device keys?

-John